# Java SE : generics and inheritance/polymorphism

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, collections

I have a `class Message` and a list of message : `List<Message> messages`

I cannot do `List<Object> objects = messages;` I know that.

But I can do this without compilation errors :

```
Object object = messages;
List<Object> myList = (List<Object>) object;
myList.add(new Object());
```

Then my `messages` list can contain any object and not just Message objects. Why is that ?

Comment: it is the myList list which contains any object. messages has no longer anything to do with it.

Comment: sure but myList and messages are referencing the same object on the heap (an instance of List<Message>). In that case why "List<Object> objects = messages" is forbidden ??

Comment: @robingood If he cast a `List<Message>` to a `List<Object>`, it's still the same object.

Comment: Java generics are there to help you avoid mistakes. When you cast around them, you bypass the checks that are there to prevent this.

Comment: Without compilation errors, yes.  But not without compiler warnings.  Turn on all compiler warnings, and pay attention to them.  The compiler will tell you that your cast is unsafe.  (You can even use `-Werror` to make the compiler treat them as errors.)

Answer (score 1):

Casting `messages` to a `List<Object>` will make your essential `Message` instances be treated like `Object` instances and nothing more (at Runtime).

Additionally, you can somewhere cast these `Object`s back to `Message`, but the compiler cannot give any guarantees that you won't get a `ClassCastException` at Runtime (because it could be that you pick the `new Object()` instance and try to cast it to `Message`)

That's actually the reason why `myList.add(new Object())` compiles - the compiler doesn't complain, because that added instance conforms the content definition of `myList`.

Not related to your question problem, but probably worth mentioning is that the casting operation is actually highly discouraged, as it's an indicator of a poor object design.